# Change output shape of two merged layers in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create a model for argument mining, which takes two sentences as input and return a single output, whether the two are neural, disagreeing or agreeing. The model is build with two bidirectional LSTM layers which get merged into a single layer, [Model can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7dbQ.png). The problem is that the output layers shape is (timestamps, label) where I would like it to be a single output of shape (1, label).

```
    LstmLayer = LSTM(32, activation='tanh', return_sequences=False)
    left_input = Input(shape=(1000,), dtype='float32', name='left_input')
    right_input = Input(shape=(1000,), dtype='float32', name='right_input')

    left = Embedding(len(self.word_index) + 1,
                     100,
                     weights=[self.embeddingMatrix],
                     input_length=1000,
                     trainable=False)(left_input)
    left = Bidirectional(LstmLayer, merge_mode='concat')(left)

    right = Embedding(len(self.word_index) + 1,
                     100,
                     weights=[self.embeddingMatrix],
                     input_length=1000,
                     trainable=False)(right_input)
    right = Bidirectional(LstmLayer, merge_mode='concat')(right)

    merged = kl.concatenate([left, right], axis=1)
    merged = Dense(32, activation='tanh')(merged)
    main_output = Dense(self.OUTPUT_SIZE, activation='softmax', name='main_output')(merged)
    self.model = Model(inputs=[left_input, right_input], outputs=[main_output])
```

The summary of the model can be seen below:

```
    Layer (type)                     Output Shape      Param #         Connected to                     
    =====================================================================
    left_input (InputLayer)         (None, 1000)         0            
    right_input (InputLayer)        (None, 1000)         0                    
    embedding_1 (Embedding)         (None, 1000, 100)    629600      left_input[0][0]
    embedding_2 (Embedding)         (None, 1000, 100)    629600      right_input[0][0]
    bidirectional_1 (Bidirectional) (None, 64)           34048       embedding_1[0][0]
    bidirectional_2 (Bidirectional) (None, 64)           34048       embedding_2[0][0]
    concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 128)          0           bidirectional_1[0][0]
                                                                     bidirectional_2[0][0]
    dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 32)           4128        concatenate_1[0][0]
    main_output (Dense)             (None, 3)            99          dense_1[0][0]  
    ======================================================================
    Total params: 1,331,523
    Trainable params: 72,323
    Non-trainable params: 1,259,200
```

The prediction function encodes the two sentences to the same length, and tokenize them with the pre-trained tokenizer which the model used.

```
 pred = self.model.predict([self._encode_sentences(sentence1), self._encode_sentences(sentence2)])
    return pred
```

If i predict on ("I am looking at a dog", "I am looking at a cat"), the output shape is (21,3)

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong here?! The output of the model has a shape of `(None, 3)` so it means classifying each sample into one of three classes and that's what you want.

Comment: @Jakobo06, you understand that `timestamps=1000`, right?

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want:

> I would like it to be a single output of shape `(1, label)`.

You can obtain it getting the last output in the output sequence i.e `result_matrix[-1]`.

```
pred = self.model.predict([self._encode_sentences(sentence1), self._encode_sentences(sentence2)])
return pred[-1]
```

as this is the **last state** of model prediction with any of the given two input sentences.